# Workaround for Teradata identity columns and volatile/temp tables issue

Tags: teradata, temp-tables, identity-column

I'm somewhat new to Teradata and cannot understand why I can't select an identity column within a volatile table. When executing something like the following, I get the error below.

```
create multiset volatile table Temp_Events as
  (
    select es.eventSettingId, -- this is an identity column 
           evt.lob
    from ForecastDevDW.cal_eventSettings es
    join ForecastDevDW.cal_eventTypes evt
     on evt.eventTypeId = es.eventTypeId
  )
with data
  primary index (eventSettingId)
  on commit preserve rows;
```

> ERROR: CREATE TABLE AS currently does not support Identity Columns.

Is there any way to select identity columns in a volatile/temporary table in Teradata? Any workarounds for this error? Also, does anyone know why you can't select identity columns within a volatile table? (I'm used to SQL Server and this is not an issue at all there.)

Comment: I haven't run into this particular issue yet. If I had to work around it, I would do a CREATE VOLATILE DDL specifying the column and column type (like a regular CREATE TABLE statement). Then follow up with an INSERT INTO... SELECT statement. Perhaps that will be allowed.

Comment: Teradata doesn't support identity columns in volatile tables, I don' t think.  You can make it an integer column and populate it using row_number, or something along those lines.

Comment: Perhaps, building on @Andrew s comment  `SELECT CAST(es.eventSettingID as INT) as eventSettingID...` ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried @JNevill s cast idea but received the same error.

Comment: Darn! I thought maybe we'd get lucky on that. I would try creating your volatile table, then inserting into it `CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE temp_events (eventSettingID INT, evt.lob WHATEVER) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` And then `INSERT INTO temp_events <your select statement here>;`

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. Creating the empty volatile table then inserting did the trick.

Comment: Great news. Odd that we have to work around that, but I'm sure there is a good reason for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a strange restriction indeed, even typecasting to a VarChar fails with the same error message.

But there's a workaround, put the Select in a Derived Table:

```
create multiset volatile table Temp_Events as
  (
    select *
    from
     (
       select es.eventSettingId, -- this is an identity column 
              evt.lob
       from ForecastDevDW.cal_eventSettings es
       join ForecastDevDW.cal_eventTypes evt
         on evt.eventTypeId = es.eventTypeId
     ) as dt
  )
with data
  primary index (eventSettingId)
  on commit preserve rows;
```

Comment: This works for a scenario where you are creating a static table which is a subset from something larger. If you were to add additional data to this table you would have to be cognizant that the primary index is not going to behave like a native identity column. Either you have to replicate this workaround from a table with an identity column or you are on the hook for producing a surrogate value for the primary index.