# How to copy 100+ tables with identity columns from one Teradata database to another?

Tags: sql, teradata, ddl

For a project I have to copy 100+ tables from one database to another. I attempted to do this by writing a cursor that excecutes:

```sql
create table {DataBaseName.TableName} as {Existing DataBaseName.TableName} with data and statistics
```

however the `create table as` functionality currently does not support [Identity Columns](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Data-Definition-Language-Detailed-Topics/March-2019/CREATE-TABLE-Options/CREATE-TABLE-Column-Definition-Clause/Identity-Columns). A [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884623/workaround-for-teradata-identity-columns-and-volatile-temp-tables-issue) posted on Stackoverflow recommends using [Derived Tables](https://docs.teradata.com/r/huc7AEHyHSROUkrYABqNIg/e8X_3NDLSEX8nn97ZdDghA). However in the process of this method the Identity Column is lost.

Is there another method to copy multiple tables automatically, while ensuring that the DDL is in the exact same state as before copying?

**Note #1:** [Data Transfer Wizard](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-StudioTM-User-Guide/September-2019/Data-Transfer/Data-Transfer-Wizard/About-the-Data-Transfer-Wizard) is not an option since I would have to copy 100+ tables manually.

**Note #2:** Generating the DDL of the whole database is also not an option, as Teradata crashes when attempting to.

Comment: backup and restore?

Comment: You potentially could do something like SHOW TABLE to obtain the DDL and use that to create empty target tables. But you may need to change `GENERATED ALWAYS` columns to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` and also change the starting value for new generated keys (since SHOW will return the original starting value). Using BAR is probably simpler.